# getting error whle running hive : org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException hive error and many more

Tags: hadoop, hive, mahout

my .bashrc

> getting error while running hive:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException hive error and many more
>
> ## Java
>
> ```
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle 
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
> ```
>
> ## Hadoop
>
> ```
> export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop 
> export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
> export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
> export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
> export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
> export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
> export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"
> export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
> export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
> export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
> ```
>
> ## Mahout
>
> ```
> export MAHOUT_HOME=/usr/local/mahout
>
> # HBase
> export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase
> export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_HOME/bin
> ```
>
> ## Hive
>
> ```
> export HIVE_HOME=/home/yash/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin
> export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
>
>  My hive-site.xml:
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
> <configuration>
> <property>
>   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
>   <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
>   <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
>   <value>root</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
>   <value>root</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
>   <value>true</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>   <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
>   <value>true</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
>  <value>True</value>
>  </property>
> <property>
>     <name>hive.querylog.location</name>
>     <value>/home/yash/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/iotmp</value>
>     <description>Location of Hive run time structured log file</description>
>   </property>
>   <property>
>     <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
>     <value>/home/yash/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/iotmp</value>
>     <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
>   </property>
>   <property>
>     <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
>     <value>/home/yash/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/iotmp</value>
>     <description>Temporary local directory for added resources in the        remote file system.</description>
>   </property>
> </configuration>
>  <i>ERROR<i>
>
>     SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>     SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/yash/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>     SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>     SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>     SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
>     Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/yash/hive/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
> ```
>
> Async: true
>           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:239)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
>           Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:366)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
>             ... 9 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1627)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3317)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3356)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3336)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3590)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
>             ... 14 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1625)
>             ... 23 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.1
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:169)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:136)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:95)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDataSourceProps(ObjectStore.java:402)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:275)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.(RawStoreProxy.java:58)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:581)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:546)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:608)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:398)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6396)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
>             at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
>             ... 28 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error starts at `Caused by ... Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 3.0.1`...

I do not think Mahout supports Hadoop 3.x yet ; you also appear to be using Hive 2.x, which does not support Hadoop 3 either

Use at least the latest Hadoop 2.7 or 2.8